# How do I combine different indexes in a "more like this" query?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

The docs of the [MLT query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) give following example (abbreviated by me) to retrieve a document similar to an existing document:

```
"query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["title", "description"],
            "like" : [
            {
                "_index" : "imdb",
                "_id" : "1"
            }],
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }
```

Which seems to compare the "title" and "description" fields among movie titles to the one movie with ID 1. Suppose I have an index for people's comments though and I would like to get all movie titles which have a "title" or "description" similar to one particular comment.

I know that I could provide free text as a value for the "like" field - the document (comment) is already part of another index though, so I would like to use that one. Just not based on the "title" and "description" fields (which would not exist on a comment), but let's say its "body" field. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same alias on both indexes : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

and run the query against the alias

note: this will cause a higher load on your elastic cluster.

Comment: Thanks, the documents within these indexes are different though - given query will check the "title" and "description" fields of any movie based on the "title" and "description" fields of movie with ID 1, but I need it to check the "title" and "description" fields of any movie based on the "body" field of my comment.

Comment: You will need to modify your query to add the fields in both index , the results of the query will give you the result for was index separately . you will need to the stiching of the fields from the different  indexes based the business logic.